# Timesheet report generation

Tags: rally

I would like to create custom timesheet report in rally to track Dev daily activity.
Does anybody know in what conditions a "Type" of report field is disabled? Currently I can't select a Timesheet report type..

Answer (score 0):

The most-likely cause is it doesn't think your workspace has Time-Tracking enabled.  Are you sure your workspace has it enabled?

Comment: That's the case. This option is not visible for me (In general tab for workspace). My user has a subscription Admin privileges which are required according to Rally's web manual. I am wondering if option of enabling this function requires some additional activation on teh top of workspace options...